# Выправь текст

Tags: грамотная-речь

Почему "Выправь текст" является ошибкой и так не говорят и не пишут? Как тогда правильно писать? Или выправь вообще не употребляется со словом текст?

Answer (score 2):

ИЗ СЛОВАРЯ: Выправить; что. Внести  необходимые исправления, правку во что-н. В.  рукопись. В.  корректуру. Выправь и выправи; св. что.

ГРАММАТИЧЕСКАЯ СПРАВКА

В грамматике-80 приводится правило выбора суффикса И/нулевого суффикса при образовании формы повелительного наклонения.

Форма повел. наклонения образуется от основы настоящего времени:

1) если в 1-ом лице ударение падает на окончание, то обычно используется суффикс И: пишу - пиши.

2) если в 1-ом лице ударение падает на основу, то обычно используется нулевой суффикс: читаю- читай, режу - режь. Исключение: а) скопление согласных: помню - помни, морщу - морщи. в) приставка ВЫ: несУ - вЫнесу - вЫнеси, гоню - выгоню - выгони (приставка ВЫ перетягивает на себя ударение,выбор делается для бесприставочного глагола).

3) В некоторых случаях возможны ВАРИАНТЫ, причем нулевой суффикс чаще используется в разговорной речи, а суффикс И - в остальных случаях: выставить - выставлю - выстави/выставь.

РЕШЕНИЕ

1) Править - прАвлю - правь, испрАвить - испрАвлю - исправь.

2) Выправить - выправлю - выправь, нулевой суффикс - это вариант по правилу.

3) Выправи - суффикс И как вариант, И в словаре он занимает ВТОРУЮ позицию.

4) И здесь начинается конфликт двух форм: нулевой суффикс выбран по правилу, но он имеет разговорный характер; суффикс И не соответствует правилу, но при этом не разговорный,  а как бы книжный и нейтральный.

ВЫВОД: Можно использовать обе формы, но вариант "выправь" встречается чаще, имеет смысл считать его основным. "Да билетец, билетец-то выправь" (М. Салтыков-Щедрин).